# How to show String result in android text view from unpredictable String[ ] length?

Tags: android

I have String[ ]Result as a result from my project. So, the String length is unstable, depend on the input. So, how can I show this string result with android text view. For example:

```
    String[]Mypermission = {............};
    String[]permissions = {......input......}  //input array
    String[]Result = null;
    for(int i=0; i<Mypermission.length; i++)
    {
       for(int j=0; j<permissions.length; j++)
       {
           if(Mypermission[i].equals(permissions[j].substring(permissions[j].lastIndexOf("."))))
           { int k=0; Result[k]= Mypermission[i]; k++;}
       }
    }
```

I can't think off how to write the result_xml layout. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its very simple only you have to set the android:singleLine="false" 
for example see below:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="asdddddddddddddddddddd5644444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444"/>
```

so this allows you to specify textview for unpredictable lengths

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display array of strings called result[] in a text view ?right ? If so then add this line  at the end of your code

---

```
    for (int i = 0; result[].lenght(); i++) {
        Mytextview.text= result[i]+"\n";
    }
```

---

you also need to enable your text view to be able to show more than one line which you can use Manoj way(xml way) or just add this code to your textview in code.     `myTextView.setSingleLine(false);`

Comment: @Bastami1982- Please tell me again. I'm not clear about it. Thank you.